# How can I pass two arguments to Pool.starmap()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

Originally, with the code I was using, Pool.map was sufficient for threading my code as there was only one argument (an, iterable) being passed in as a parameter to my function.  Now, I have a requirement to pass in multiple arguments to the function and I'm having some trouble using Pool.starmap.

I attempted to use zip alongside Pool.map to no avail.

Here's my current code:

```
def get_links_on_page(job_title, page_num):
    page = requests.get("%s/jobs?q=%s&l=%s%%2C%s&start=%s" % (__SITE_BASE__, job_title.replace(' ', '+'), 'City', 'PROV', str(page_num*25)), verify=False)
    print(page.url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    return [link.a.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'title'})]


def get_all_links(job_title):
    """
    :param: job_title (string): A string representing the job's title
    """

    all_links = []
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=20)
    all_links.extend(pool.starmap(get_links_on_page, (job_title, [i for i in range(1, 5)]))) 
    pool.close()
    return all_links
```

This gives me an error like:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

I also attempted to pass in the two arguments as an iterable like so:

```
def get_all_links(job_title):
    all_links = []
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=20)
    all_links.extend(pool.starmap(get_links_on_page, [job_title, [i for i in range(1, 5)]])) #[func(job_title, 1), func(job_title, 2), func(job_title, 3) ...]
    pool.close()
    return all_links
```

And that would equate to 18 arguments and thus throw an error.
I'm currently reading the docs here:

https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap

But I'm having trouble getting the syntax down..

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: @Darkonaut Ah, sorry, let me add some function documentation

Comment: @Darkonaut Awesome it worked! If you want to add a reply I'll mark you as the solution.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've been on the right track with using `zip()`, you just need to `repeat()` the job_title:

```
list(zip(itertools.repeat("jobname"), range(1, 5)))
# [('jobname', 1), ('jobname', 2), ('jobname', 3), ('jobname', 4)]
```

So for your example:

```
from itertools import repeat

def get_all_links(job_title, n): # n would be 4 in your example
    iterable = zip(repeat(job_title), range(1, n+1))
    with ThreadPool(n) as pool:
        all_links = pool.starmap(get_links_on_page, iterable)
    return all_links
```

Comment: This worked out perfectly for me.  Much appreciated good sir.

Comment: Hi,  my `job_title` is `numpy.array` with shape `(10000,10)`, and I repeat `11` times, but `starmap` doesn't work. It only work when the `job_title` is small. How to solve it?